# Are newer questions always considered the duplicate between the two?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, views

I thought this was interesting, a question [I asked](https://superuser.com/questions/443872/my-power-supply-whines-is-there-anything-i-can-do-about-it?noredirect=1#comment1094053_443872) 2 years ago was just marked as a duplicate. When I followed [the link](https://superuser.com/questions/832480/why-do-some-ac-adapters-and-power-supplies-generate-a-whining-noise-and-what-ca) the question was infact very simillar to mine, except it had only been asked yesterday. I'm glad to see it got answers, as mine didn't recieve much attention. Can anyone explain why @
Rishat Muhametshin question got 24 upvotes and several answers and mine didn't get any?

Is there a policy as to which question is considered the duplicate? I did ask mine first.